# Would this algorithm fail to count solutions $>$ $1$ for Exact-3-cover?

Tags: np-complete, decision-problem

Decision Problem: Given a set $S$, is there at least a given $N$ $>$ $1$ amount of solutions, for an $Exact~Cover~by~3-sets$ for $C%$?

$s$ = $1,2,3,4,5,6$

$c$ = $[[1,2,3],[4,3,2],[4,5,6],[5,1,6],[5,6,3]]$

### Solutions

$[1,2,3],[4,5,6]$

$[4,3,2],[5,1,6]$

$N$ = $2$

Yes, there are $N$ solutions.

### Algorithm

1. Remove sets that have repeating elements

   (eg. [1,1,2] is deleted from $C$)
2. Remove sets that have elements that don't exist in $S$

   (eg. [9,5,6] is deleted because $9$ not in $S$)
3. Make sure all elements in $S$ exist in $C$.

$for$ a $in$ $range(0, length(s)):$

$~~~~~~~~$$IF$ $s[a]$ $not$ in $c$:

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~$OUTPUT NO

### Convert $C$ into a complete list

$WHILE$ $c[i]$ has [brackets]:

$~~~~~~~~~~$ DELETE [BRACKETS] FROM $C$

now $c$ = $[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 5, 1, 6, 5, 6, 3]$

### Finally, Decide

$n$ = $('Enter~for~N:~'))$

$yes$ = $0$

$for$ a $in$ $range$(0, $length(c)):$

$~~~~~~$$if$ $c$.count($c$[a]) >= $n$ :

$~~~~~~~~~~$$yes$ = $1$

$~~~~~~$else:

$~~~~~~~~~~$OUTPUT NO

$~~~~~~~~~~$HALT

$if$ $yes$ == $1$ :

$~~~~$OUTPUT YES

Edit: The above should do the same below.

```
yes = 0
for a in range(0, length(s)):
    if c.count(s[a]) >= n:
        yes = 1
    else:
        OUTPUT('No')
        break

if yes == 1:
    OUTPUT('yes')
```

### Facts to consider

1. There cannot be any sets with elements that don't exist in $S$.
2. There cannot be any sets with repeating elements.
3. All elements in $S$ must exist in $C$. Else, a $no$ is given.
4. $N$ must be > $1$
5. If any element in $C$ occurs < $N$ times then the output must be $No$, because there wouldn't be at least $N$ solutions.

**Question**

Will this algorithm always work if the input is > $1$, and if no how would it fail?

Comment: If it fails, I will resort to using the counting method for $S$ and compare it to the number of times $S[a]$ occurs in $C$.

Comment: (eg. ^^^ if c.count(s[a]) >= n: ^^^^) (loop through s)

Comment: $S = \{1, ..., 9\}$. $C = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [4, 8, 9], [5, 6, 7]]$ $N=2$

Comment: @VladislavBezhentsev Where is your input for $N$?

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my comment.

Comment: @VladislavBezhentsev Your input must be > 1.

Comment: @VladislavBezhentsev The output says No. There is no 2 solutions because 9 is not divisible by 2??? I'm guessing.

Comment: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]] and
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 8, 9], [5, 6, 7]]
Why these solutions are bad?

Comment: @VladislavBezhentsev If $S$ = $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ Your solutions would be $[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]$ and $[[1, 2, 3], [4, 8, 9], [5, 6, 7]]$ Notice there are two solutions. Which means each integer occurs $N$ times. (2) You gave a yes solution.

Comment: >>"Which means each integer occurs N times." Occurs where? In the provided above set $C$ numbers $1, 2$ and $3$ occur only once.

Comment: @VladislavBezhentsev pastebin of my algorithm in python if you ever want to run it yourself.-link https://pastebin.com/BTNMG5bZ

Comment: @VladislavBezhentsev [1,2,3] occurs twice in $[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]$ and $[[1, 2, 3], [4, 8, 9], [5, 6, 7]]$

Comment: I've just run your algorithm. It prints "no" on my input, as I expected. But the correct answer is "yes", isn't it?

Comment: @VladislavBezhentsev Give me your input.

Comment: @VladislavBezhentsev There have to be at least 2 solutions or a No is returned.

Comment: I ran it on input that we have discussed above. Do you agree that this input has at least two solutions?

Comment: @VladislavBezhentsev If it this one (the one in the code) then you are right. Perhaps it return no, because [1,2,3] is not used twice. Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: @VladislavBezhentsev Now, I found a special case when numbers are used twice it should be trivial??? Not sure, but it was interesting to poke around this problem.

Comment: @VladislavBezhentsev Something just clicked. if len(c) <= len(s)//3*3:.......
    for jj in combinations(c, len(s)//3): Hmmm... I come back in a week to this stack for another question if you are every interested in answering.

Comment: What are you trying to do? It's HIGHLY unlikely that you will be able to find a poly-time algorithm for an NP-complete problem.

Comment: @VladislavBezhentsev No, make algorithms more practical for average inputs at least.

Comment: Before asking here, I recommend that you first implement your algorithm and test it on a large number of random test cases (compare its output to a known-good algorithm, e.g., one that does an exhaustive search) and check whether it is always correct on all such test cases.